# Problem with mounting a partition

Tags: linux, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I typed **fdisk -l** and here is the part of it's output related to this question of mine

```
.
.
/dev/sda5     2989   5600   20971520 7  HPFS/NTFS 
/dev/sda6     5600   8211   20971520 7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda7     8211   10822  20971520 7  HPFS/NTFS 
. 
.
```

Now, when i mounted **/dev/sda6** as

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda6 /home/Partition
```

following error poped up

```
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sda6': No such file or a directory
```

Then the ouput of ntfs-3g --help is printed telling me how to use ntfs-3g.

I also tried **ntfs **/dev/sda6**** but it gave a similar error, saying

```
Failed to determine whether /dev/sda6 is mounted; No such file or directory
Mounting volume.... Error opening partition device: No such file or directory
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors...Error opening partition device: No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk
```

And I don't have **chkdsk** command available on **Finnix**, the distributin I am using right now.

Any ideas to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The errors you see generally mean that the NTFS-3g driver detects some errors or corruption on the filesystem.  The NTFS-3g driver is playing it safe by refusing to mount the partition.

When it says you should run `chkdsk`, it means you should boot into Windows and run `chkdsk` on the drive from there.  Microsoft designed NTFS, and their tools are much safer for risky operations like correcting these kinds of corruption.

You can try running `ntfsfix` if you have the `ntfsprogs` package installed.  It fixes some common NTFS problems, but it is *not* a replacement for `chkdsk`.  From the [ntfsfix(8) manpage](http://man.linux-ntfs.org/ntfsfix.8.html):

> **ntfsfix** is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk. It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

If you absolutely must mount it *now*, you can use the `-o force` mount option.  This causes NTFS-3g to clear the unclean NTFS logfile.  **Use with caution.  Running *chkdsk* on the filesystem from within Windows is a much safer alternative.**

Comment: ntfsfix did not solve the problem. Seems like there is something wrong with the distribution I used i.e. Finnix 93.0 because with Debian I have never faced this problem. Any thoughts quixote? :)

Comment: @usajbait: i did tell you ntfsfix wasn't a chkdsk replacement.  you have some options.  (1) boot into Windows and run chkdsk. (2) make sure /dev/sda6 exists, and that it is recognized properly in fdisk and (g)parted. (3) use a different distribution.  (4) upgrade (or downgrade) your kernel or NTFS-3g driver. (5) reformat the partition and restore the data from backup.